# Safest way to efficiently modify set element that is used as a key

Tags: c++, performance, set, undefined-behavior

I have `std::set<std::set<T>>` whose inner sets I need to modify frequently.

How can I do this efficiently? The only ways I can come up with either seem to cause undefined behavior or cause the entire inner set to be copied, both of which seem like bad ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) allows for in-place modification of elements, as the example shows:

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/960ef77bcc85e266)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <set>

template<typename T>
using set_set=boost::multi_index_container<
  std::set<T>,
  boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
    boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
      boost::multi_index::identity<std::set<T>>
    >
  >
>;

int main()
{
  set_set<int> ss={{0,1,2},{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{6,4,5}};

  auto it=ss.find(std::set<int>{6,4,5}); // get last element
  ss.modify(it,[](auto& s){
    s.erase(6);   // change 6
    s.insert(3);  // for 3
  });
  assert((*it==std::set<int>{3,4,5}));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just make the inner type *not* a `set`:

```
struct DerefComparator {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const
    {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};

std::set<std::shared_ptr<std::set<T>>, DerefComparator> the_set;
auto it = the_set.find(...);

// copy out - doesn't copy the whole set
auto inner = *it;
the_set.erase(it);

// make modifications as before
inner->insert(...);
inner->erase(...);

// move in
the_set.insert(std::move(inner));
```

Comment: I'm not worried about the const cast, I'm worried about the erasure causing a comparison.

Comment: @Mehrdad That's a fair worry - that's why I deleted that part of my answer. The `shared_ptr` case definitely won't have that issue.

Comment: +1 Okay so that introduces a second heap allocation, but I think I get it now and we can avoid that as well -- we basically need a wrapper that can switch from the original object to a new object (I imagine a `struct { mutable T value; T *p; <wrapper methods for comparator> }` would work as well).

Comment: @Mehrdad If you're using `set`, you're already doing heap allocations on every operation right?

Comment: @Barry: Assuming I'm using a standard allocator, yeah, but there's no need to make it twice as slow as it needs to be :)